# Auto creating records across a ManyToMany Field in Django upon save

Tags: python, django, relationship, django-models

I'm building a site where I have a 'Skills' section, where users can type in what skills they have and save them.  Since I plan for this to be searchable and I'll want data on it as well, I'm creating a separate `Skill` model that will host the list of skills that my `Users` model has a `ManyToMany` field on.

Since I won't know ahead of time what skills there will be, I'll need to generate those records automatically.  I have already tried using the `pre_save` signal on the `Users` model to create any Skills that may not exist yet, but since I'll have this functionality a number of times, I'd like to create an `AutoPopulateManyToMany` field that creates new records in the related model upon save of the calling model if they don't yet exist.

I'm having trouble figuring out which methods to override when subclassing `ManyToManyField` in order to stick the code that would create the new skills.  I expect that code would look something along the lines of, specifically for skills:

```
for item in <list of skills>:
    if not Skill.objects.filter(name=item):
        self.skills.create(name=name)
```

Or, more generalized, this would look something like the following:

```
for item in <related model items>:
    if not related_model.objects.filter(**{filter_field: item}):
        self.related_model_m2m_field.create(**{filter_field: item})
```

I just can't figure out where in the `ManyToManyField` object's creation process when saving a new item it goes.  In particular, I'm not even sure that I'm able to access the class that the field is a part of from the `Field` object itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the where to put the "create skills" function, but consider this implementation:

```
for missing_name in set(skill_names) - set(Skill.objects.filter(name__in=skill_list).values_list('name',flat=True) ):
    _ = Skill.objects.get_or_create(name=missing_name)
```

It does a single query to find out all given skill names which already exist in the database.  Then for each name that doesn't exist, try to create it. If the skill is created in between the `filter()` and the `get_or_create()` -- you have a race condition -- then safely move on.

(The `_` notation means "I'm calling a function that returns a result, but I'm explicitly ignoring it."  You could also do a `try/except` block.)